# How to unload an injected DLL from target process, from the DLL when done?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, dll-injection

I have a DLL that injects itself using the CreateRemoteThread/LoadLibrary method.

It is cumbersome to quit the target application and restart it (it has a loading time of 10-20 seconds) when debugging and developing the DLL, so I want to unload the DLL when I have checked that what my code does works, to recompile / re-inject it.

I want to avoid creating a new DLL with a framework for loading and unloading said DLL.

How is this possible?

Comment: You'll need to do the same way as when you inject code to load the library, except that you need to inject a code to unload the library in its own process context. Have the code injected after the library is no longer needed. This should be done in the very last function where you still have control. However, you'll will need assembly knowledge to make the *library unloader* code.

Comment: What sort of DLL is it? and do you have control over the calling application? If it's COM you can pick up on the reference counting. If you can control the host, just release it all and call `FreeLibrary()`.

Comment: @Deanna: correct, it is just simple as that!

Comment: I have control of the process doing the injection, but not the process being injected. My next question sort of, I spawn a thread from DllMain which does it's job, do I call FreeLibrary(GetModuleHandle(L"My.dll")) the very last, when I tell the thread to end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) spawns a thread, and when that thread is complete with whatever it is doing, you can use [FreeLibraryAndExitThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The FreeLibraryAndExitThread function allows threads that are executing within a DLL to safely free the DLL in which they are executing and terminate themselves. **If they were to call FreeLibrary and ExitThread separately, a race condition would exist. The library could be unloaded before ExitThread is called.**

From that quote, I state in plain english that you should **not call this function from within DllMain**.